# Installing my own extension in Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online)

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to create a Build Task in Visual Studio Team Services. I've followed this guide: https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task

I can complile the VIX-package and successfully upload it to the Marketplace.

However, when I try to "Install" it in my own (or another) Team Services then it says:

> Only the Visual Studio Team Services account administrator can install
>   this extension in account

I'm positive that I'm the "Account administrator" as I am the only user :)
And, I have double checked in "Settings" that this is the case.

If I try to click "Request Install" then an e-mail is sent to the very same account I'm logged into. If I then click "Approve" in the e-mail then says that I have already requested this extension.

What to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this again. This was some issue with VSTS on 3/10 that made the owners/admins cannot install extensions from Marketplace.

> Final Update: Friday, 10 March 2016 15:30 UTC
>
> We've confirmed that all systems are back to normal as of 10 March
>   2016 15:00 UTC. Customers should no longer see any issues with
>   Marketplace.
>
> We understand that customers rely on VS Team Services as a critical
>   service and apologize for any impact this incident caused.
>
> Sincerely,  Sukanta
>
> ---
>
> Initial Update: Thursday, 10 March 2016 13:45 UTC
>
> We are actively investigating issues with Marketplace. A small subset
>   of VSTS account owners/ admins will not be able to install extensions
>   from Marketplace.
>
> We are working to resolve this issue and apologize for any
>   inconvenience.
>
> Sincerely, Sukanta

Information from: [Investigating issues with Marketplace in Visual Studio Team Services - 03/10](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsoservice/archive/2016/03/10/investigating-issues-with-marketplace-in-visual-studio-team-services-03-10-investigating.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I do confirm that this kind of issue don't occur anymore on VSTS Marketplace. I am able to install app on VSTS. Did you guys had issue after uploading the extension (task.json could not be found in the package?)